# php read clob data when empty rows

Tags: php, oracle, plsql, clob

I have problem reading clob data. After empty row no more data are retrieved. If I have data in row1, row2, row4 and row3 is empty I only get data from row1 and row2.

```
$select = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT DESCRIPTION FROM PRODUCTS");
oci_execute($select);
while($row = oci_fetch_array($select, OCI_ASSOC)){
echo $row["DESCRIPTION"]->load();
$row["DESCRIPTION"]->free();
}
```

Comment: did you try:  while (($row = oci_fetch_array($select, OCI_ASSOC)) != false)

Comment: tried, not working

Answer (score 0):

found a way to deal with this

```
"SELECT CASE WHEN DESCRIPTION IS NULL THEN TO_CLOB('-') ELSE DESCRIPTION END DESCRIPTION FROM PRODUCTS"
```